# Motion tracking, several objects, changing shape

Tags: image-processing, tracking, shapes

I am working on a project where i try to track movement of leafs in a video stream. The problem is that the leafs are both moving and changing shape during the video. My experience on the topic is limited and i would like to ask if someone who got experience with the stated problem could help me to walk in the correct direction?

Two images from the videostream are linked below. Notice that this is not two subsequent images, but an example on how the objects that i want to track is changed. The movement from frame to frame is smaller and is smooth in the video.

[Plant where all the leafs is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYyLW.png)

[Plant where leafs is closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efAGi.png)

The superb solution would be a method which find some sort of relative movement of the leafs (the leaf stem seems to be static in some situations where the leafs are moving alot). My object is to find if there is a pattern in the movement, so some sort of mean "global tracking" might be as good as a "regional tracking" of individual leafs. The videostream i am working on i rather large (4000 - 10 000 images), so suggestions to computional in-expensive methods would also be most appriciated.

Kind regards

Comment: What do you mean with track? I understand if someone wants to track a ball that is rolling through a scene or people moving around. But a plant on a very nice segmented image? What is it you are interested in? Is it not sufficient to monitor the area-change of the leaf or something?

Comment: Hi and thank you for the reply. I have uploaded a small sequence of the video stream (not post-processed) that show how the plant is moving. [Leaf Movement Video](https://youtu.be/a_Oyx0aP-bo).  I mean that i want to track/estimate the global or regional movement of the leafs in the video.

Comment: Dense Optical Flow springs to mind: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssINeWRb58M, http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/optflow/doc/dense_optflow.html. You can track the movement of every pixel in the scene by backtracking the measured optical flow vectors.

Comment: Thank you, i will certainly check that out!